# How to line up the pieces at the coast near the shipwreck?

Tags: the-witness

In *The Witness*, I was walking along the coast, and I came upon this:

[image: A beautiful seaside picture]

Now, since I've learned

> that mazes can be embedded in the environment,

I see the puzzle here, but I just can't get the pieces to line up well enough.  Standing on the couch and walking all around it doesn't seem to get me a

> functional maze.

Where do I need to stand to activate the puzzle successfully?

Comment: I went past this very sofa last night, didnt see this. Is there a building behind the sofa where there's a higher vantage point? Also - the circle doesn't look whole? As if it's a 'broken' version of this type of puzzle. Pure conjecture =)

Comment: @SpaceBison Yes, but from what I recall, there's no higher place with a sight line to the puzzle.

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253824/3921

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you stand in front of the couch, the pieces will line up to make the path.

[image: Solution with missing chunk]

This is the correct position; however the starting-circle has a rectangular gap, and a large chunk of the path is missing...

Hint:

> There is something orange and movable that can fill in the gap.

Solution:

> Set the boat off on its own, then run back and wait for it to pass by.
>
>  [image: Puzzle solution]

Comment: Would never have thought of doing that.

Comment: Wow, an amazing puzzle... like every other in this game with the boat invovled.

Comment: My wife and I spent the better part of two hours trying to finagle the perspective on this puzzle.  If I hadn't managed to make it "sparkle" without the boat I wouldn't be half as angry as I am now.

Comment: I recall there's a name for this: "Ghost ride" (ghost-riding the boat)

Comment: The sparkle really just tells you that you are on to something (unfortunately, the sparkle does not provide information on whether you are getting closer, merely that you have just begun). I feel your pain.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the other end of that piece of metal. It's not round, you can't end a puzzle there. But you CAN end the puzzle on the piece of metal a bit further over. You'll need something orange to bridge the gap.