# Sofa blocking puzzle

Tags: the-witness

Ok, so I've spotted another one of the dot+line patterns that I want to click, however, I don't seem to be able to stand in the right spot to get a perfect circle.

There's a sofa exactly where I need to stand. I can get *really* close (close enough that I get sparks) but can't quite trigger it.

[image]

[image]

I've tried standing on the steps behind, but a tree blocks the correct position (can't even get sparks here)

[image]

And even standing on the castle wall, but the crenelations are in the way (again, no sparks)

[image]

There's nothing else on the correct line of sight.

Is this just very fiddly and I need to keep trying by the sofa or am I missing something?

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/253457/3921

Comment: Friggin' sofa...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing something. The piece of metal there doesn't end in a round part, so you can't actually draw a complete puzzle there. But there IS a round part on the metal over to the left. So you need something orange to bridge the gap.

Comment: This is a really good hint, as it highlights that the piece to the left is SO far away that perspective will not help you here.